# Compatibility of the tricky dynamic arrays with dynamic arrays

Tags: arrays, delphi, pointers, dynamic-arrays

Considering the old trick to make an array

```
Type
  IntArray = Array Of Integer;
  PIntArray = ^IntArray
  PTDynIntArray = ^TDynIntArray;
  TDynIntArray = Array[0..0] Of Integer;

{later...}

GetMem(APTDynIntArray,100*SizeOf(Integer));
APTDynIntArray^[49] := 50
```

Is There a way to make this tricky array compatible with a standard dynamic array ?

For example, If I want to translate an old (lets say from 1999) unit with

```
Procedure DoSomething(Data: PTDynIntArray);
```

And considering that the data will be processed using the above syntax (dataname-dereference-index in brackets), Delphi compiler will not stop if I pass a **PIntArray** as argument, however I get an AV at run-time (I guess that Delphi considers, in this case, that **PIntArray** Is the same as **PTDynIntArray**)

So can these two types (PIntArray and PTDynIntArray) be combined, type casted, inter-changed ? How ?

Comment: Use real dynamic arrays and remove all the ancient code

Comment: I usually do, but the question comes because of the convertion of an old unit which uses this sytem. Btw I wonder if this system is not faster for passing an array as parameter in a call. Basically as the first element is directly accessible and if the caller also pass the array size (which misses in my example)...it coulds be faster than passing the array reference.

Comment: Performance is not your issue here. Passing a pointer is trivial. Passing a dynamic array to an open array parameter is trivial. Choose what is most maintainable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert an `IntArray` (note: *not* `PIntArray`) to a `PTDynIntArray`. The reverse is not generally possible.

An `IntArray` is stored as a pointer to the first element of the array. The array is preceded by information about the array's length and such, but if your procedure only accesses the array elements, they won't do any harm.

You may, to be explicit, also write it as `@IntArray[0]`.

Comment: All right, It works fine. Now I also remember that in a Delphi object, for a dynamic array, the data actually owned by the object is only a pointer, it makes more sense...I was passing a reference to a reference of a data, not a directed reference to a data...

Comment: A good old `pointer(IntDynArray)` will points to a `PIntegerArray`. Using @IntArray[0] will reset the reference counting (which is also part of the header). And you can modify the elements if you need too - taking care of the reference counting.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez Neither `PTDynIntArray(IntDynArray)`/`IntDynArray` nor `@IntArray[0]` will do anything with the refcount; if the refcount isn't one, and you don't want your changes to affect any other users of the same array storage, you need to handle that situation manually. The only difference between the two alternatives is that `@IntArray[0]` may give a range error when `IntArray` is empty.

Comment: Oops, that /`IntDynArray` was supposed to read /`Pointer(IntDynArray)`.